# Curried functions in SWIFT

Tags: swift

After reading Ole's post http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/

What I understood is that you can call a method of any class in a different context or scope. If I understood it correctly then it's the same as `apply` or `call` in javascript.

Here's my attempt using this for the Observer pattern.

I've a problem in `self.method(self.context)(message)`, the error says `(Messaging) -> $T6 is not identical to 'Void'`

```
protocol Messaging {
    var message: String { get set }
}

class Observer {
    var method: Messaging -> Void
    var context: AnyObject

    init(method: Messaging -> Void, context: AnyObject) {
        self.method = method
        self.context = context
    }

    func notify(message: Messaging) {
        self.method(message)
        //self.method(self.context)(message) // Houston, we have a problem
    }
}

public class Message: Messaging {
    var message: String

    public init(message: String) {
        self.message = message
    }
}

class TestObserver {

    func createAndNotifiy() {
        var observer = Observer(method: self.handleMessage, context: self)
        observer.notify(Message(message: "TestMessage"))
    }

    func handleMessage(message: Messaging) -> Void {
        println(message.message)
    }
}

var test = TestObserver()
test.createAndNotifiy()
```

inside `notify` method I've attempted to call the passed method in the passed context (I've used `context` as `self` but it could be a different context too)

**My objective is to make it work for any context passed in.**

**Edit:** Is it that who's function I ever pass in, it automatically gets associated to that context, for instance `Observer(method: self.handleMessage...` in this case `handleMessage` is implicitly/explicitly bound to `self` in this case and I shouldn't really care about passing `self` as an additional param (as context), cause `self.method(message)` calls the `method` in context of the bound object automatically? that's my assumption, looking forward to a solid opinion.

but irrespective still also would like to know how to get the curried approach work in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a difference between `self.methodname` (which you are using), and `Classname.methodname`.

The former, when called within a class’s method, will give you a function bound with that class instance.  So if you call it, it will be called on that instance.

The latter gives you a curried function that takes as an argument any instance of `Classname`, and returns a new function that is bound to that instance.  At this point, that function is like the first case (only you can bind it to any instance you like).

Here’s an example to try and show that a bit better:

```
class C {
    private let _msg: String
    init(msg: String) { _msg = msg }

    func print() { println(_msg) }

    func getPrinter() -> ()->() { return self.print }
}

let c = C(msg: "woo-hoo")
let f = c.getPrinter()
// f is of type ()->()
f() // prints "woo-hoo"

let d = C(msg: "way-hey")

let g = C.print
// g is of type (C)->()-(),
// you need to feed it a C:
g(c)() // prints "woo-hoo"
g(d)() // prints "way-hey"

// instead of calling immediately,
// you could store the return of g:
let h = g(c)
// at this point, f and h amount to the same thing:
// h is of type ()->()
h() // prints "woo-hoo"
```

Finally, looks like you’re trying, with `AnyObject`, to take any kind of class and pass that into your curried instance method.  That won’t fly – that curried method will specifically need a type of the class it was taken from.  No good trying to feed it something else.

Comment: good catch, so the passing parameter has to be Classname.method, can it be applied on a protocol.method, for instance in my case `Observer(method: Observing.handleMessage, context: self)` assuming  observer conforming `Observing` protocol

Comment: nope, you can’t use the same trick with protocol methods i.e. `protocol P { f() }; let g = P.f` will not work.  But why is it you’re so keen to use a protocol for this “context"?  Is the closure capturing self not sufficient?

Comment: ok, I'm actually trying to make some use of the `context` passed to the Observer and put it to work, turns out that in this pattern, passing context is useless, the method passed itself is already bound to the context it was referred from