# Swift: Calling instance method using class name

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I was reading iOS programming: big nerd ranch guide.I am on chapter 10 and in this chapter i was reading about adding new row in tableview.
for that i need to call

```
itemStore.createItem()
```

Here is the ItemStore class

```
class ItemStore {
    var allItems = [Item]()

    func createItem() -> Item{
        let newItem = Item(random: true)
        allItems.append(newItem)
        return newItem
    }

    init(){
        for _ in 0..<5{
            createItem()
        }
    }
}
```

but by mistake i have typed class name ItemStore and after dot xcode gave me 
this option

```
() -> Item createItem(self: ItemStore)
```

and i have managed to do same thing like this

```
let newItem = ItemStore.createItem(itemStore)()
```

So from where this class method is coming? is it a syntax sugar? 
what is the significance is this?

Comment: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644702/curried-functions-in-swift